# jQuery NIC validate

Tags: jquery, regex, validation

I need regex to validate an Pakistani National ID Card (NIC) number which contains Digits and Dashes in format given below

> `12345-1234567-1`

Please help..

Comment: [What have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you can use standard javaScript to test the Regex expression:

```
var idToTest = '12345-1234567-1',
myRegExp = new RegExp(/\d{5}-\d{7}-\d/);

if(myRegExp.test(idToTest)) {
    //if true
}
else {
    //if false
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
var cnic_no = '12345-1234567-9',
var cnic_no_regex = /^[0-9+]{5}-[0-9+]{7}-[0-9]{1}$/;

if(cnic_no_regex.test(cnic_no)) 
{
    alert('Right');
}
else 
{
    alert('Wrong');
}
```

JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/k81w2x77/1/

JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/fokq2woq/10/

Answer (score 2):

This will validate it.  (As long as the format is exactly as you state)

`\d{5}-\d{7}-\d`

Answer (score 2):

this should be like that

```
myRegExp = new RegExp(/\d{5}-\d{7}-\d{1}$/);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex to validate CNIC

```
^[0-9+]{5}-[0-9+]{7}-[0-9]{1}$
```

to see how to use it in jquery function, see this [example](https://bugs.code.blog/2019/04/18/function-to-validate-cnic-using-regex/).